# Realm Java as a dependency to Native Android Library bind to Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, realm, aar

I have an Android library that contains Realm as a dependency. I need to create C# bindings for that library but I can't understand how to create bindings for Realm. Could I just download Realm Aars from bin tray, create bindings for them and add them as a reference to Xamarin project? Or there should be another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm uses generic types a lot, and as I found out Xamarin Bindings doesn't work well with them. So I couldn't create working bindings for Realm and needed to replace Realm in the library with SQLite standard database. Also, I haven't found existing bindings for Realm (Java) and because of that, I will mark this answer as correct, if u have a solution for this issue please post your answer here and if it works I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is a component available for Realm in xamarin which you can find here [Realm](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/realm)

To add this to your project :

1.Right click on components.

2.Log in with your Xamarin account. (in case you have one)

3.Search for Realm.

4.Click on Add component.

this should do the trick

In case you want that particular Aar as a dll then follow this guide :

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/

Good luck! Happy Coding.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for ur answer. I'm new to Xamarin and trying to port my Native Android Library (Java) to Xamarin project. So as far as I know I need to create bindings for it and add transitive dependencies in NuGet or create binding for them if it's not on NuGet yet. I haven't seen Realm (Java) bindings there only Realm for .NET library. I will give it a try but not sure if it would work :)

Comment: Brother Realm .Net libraries are .Net support for realm they will work in case they don't you can simply create a dll using that reference link. By the way components and NUget are different

Comment: The component store is being deprecated, which is why the Realm component available there is super outdated. Instead, use the one from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Realm/. If you are binding your native library (not porting it), then you can't use the Realm .NET and need to package the Realm Java .aar's with your library. Unfortunately, due to all the compile-time magic Realm uses, I'm not sure it'll be straightforward to do so.

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev thanks for ur answer! I couldn't create bindings for Realm so I replaced it with SQLite db.